# Find rows that have the same value and select the newer one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a table, that looks like this:

| serialNr | sensorNr | ModifyDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12EE56423 | 2022-04-06 |
| 4567 | 12EE56423 | 2018-06-12 |
| 6789 | AD3FF0C44 | 2018-03-08 |
| 9101 | AD3FF0C44 | 2019-06-07 |

From rows with the same sensorNr, I only want to select those with newer ModifyDate, so the result should look like this:

| serialNr | sensorNr | ModifyDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12EE56423 | 2022-04-06 |
| 9101 | AD3FF0C44 | 2019-06-07 |

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sensorNr ORDER BY ModifyDate DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT serialNr, sensorNr, ModifyDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
SELECT
  serialNr, sensorNr, ModifyDate
FROM
  your_table_name_goes_here
GROUP BY
  sensorNr
ORDER BY
  ModifyDate DESC
```

it will give you one row for each unique `sensorNr` and ordering by `ModifyDate` will make sure that the values for `ModifyDate` and `serialNr` will be the "newest"

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9517EvEj5GqD3agJXAiv5X/2)